# Favourite changes notification

Tags: feature-request, favorites-notifications

Has the favourite notifcation system changed?

Now every time I visit SO or SF I get a notification about changes in a favourite question.

I have before used the favourite star to mark posts I like and would like to easily get back to such as the [server name question](https://serverfault.com/questions/45734/the-coolest-server-names) or [funny loading statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182112/what-are-some-funny-loading-statements-to-keep-users-amused) but not necessarily that important that I need to be notified about new answers.

At the same time I see the usefulness in being notified on changes in relevant post without having to write an answer yourself.

Can these be implemented:

- A notification service like the star now works as
- A bookmark service as the star used to work as

Comment: Also see [abuse of the notification bar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54378/abuse-of-the-notification-bar).