# Does the notification banner annoy anyone else?

Tags: discussion, usability, design

I wouldn't have a gripe if the banner area was stationary, but often times the page will load and I'll target something with my mouse and then the banner will suddenly appear and shift the entire UI down.

I like the notification concept, but I'm often frustrated by the UI.

Just my 2 cents.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Abuse of the notification bar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54378/abuse-of-the-notification-bar)

Comment: Yes, although I'm more annoyed by the "you've been auto-logged in banner" that covers up all the top links on the site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just wish that clicking it would consistently take me to the "recent activity" page. Because that's usually where I'm headed anyway once I see it, and it makes a much more inviting click-target than that tiny little envelope... (or the tiny little X on the right)

Answer (score 0):

The top notification bar used to be blocking. It used to hover on top of the SE navigation area. Now, I still have a number of issues with the top notification bar.

- Asynchronous. After the page loads and you start reading, the page adjusts for the notification bar. This is a minor annoyance.
- Other notification mechanisms exist. For instance the global inbox, but also the 'error' pages for important notifications like downtime.
- The importance of the notifications is low. The last three notifications I received were two for comments and one for a badge. I already saw the comments in the inbox, so that's redundant. Earning a badge is not important.