# Prevent the 'Notification Fiesta'

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, notifications

This proposal is very similar to [the abuse of the notification bar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54378/abuse-of-the-notification-bar). Take a look at this screenshot:

[image: Create Account]

Three notifications! None of these are important (*):

- +100 Reputation.
- Associated accounts.
- Privileges gained.

As you can see, the notification bars are on top of the page, preventing users to access the functionality at the top of the page.

I propose all notifications get classified according to importance and less important messages could be put in the inbox.

(*) important enough to justify the disrupting the concentration of people.

Comment: You can hit the __'X'__ on the right and they go away.

Comment: @Lance Roberts nice if you go on vacation for two months and you have to click away 1337 bars.

Comment: @WTP: but who'd click away a **1337** bar?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

We actually made some changes to this last night.  When logging into a new site (associating your existing accounts at the same time) you'll see **zero** banners.

We're also hiding several badge notifications based on if you're associated ("veteran") or not (the clutter ones like [autobiographer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/9/autobiographer) that you get immediately as well).

Overall, we're reducing the amount of "banner spam" up top with things that annoy more than help, especially ones repeated on every new site you associate to.

*Edit:* also, we prefer the term "fiesta".

Comment: Nice one Nick! :)

Comment: @Nick, are you sure you're reducing the fiesta? I just got one for an answer migrated to [su]. I've had answers migrated plenty of times in the past and never got a banner about it, so it's obviously pretty new. It also feels kind of pointless... if someone leaves me a comment about it, it'll show up in my inbox anyhow. If no one leaves any comments, it doesn't matter where it lives.

Comment: @sarnold - there is a new notification here, but only if it's a *very* new post (< 3 days) or has at least one upvote...so you can see where your rep went and claim it on the destination site.

Comment: So I'm a veteran if I have 5k rep? I just passed 200 rep for the first time today so I'm guessing there will be no banner fiesta when I am awarded my badge!?

Comment: Ah nvm, I did get fiest-an-tastic bar for the mortarboard badge :D

Comment: @gideon - you still get banner notifications, but only for the important ones that are harder to get, so they're much rarer than before for power users :)

Comment: So what is the definition of notifications which are hidden? "All bronze badges once you hit 200 rep, plus all instant badges, but no others"?

Comment: Nevermind, I got my answer here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138113/which-badges-do-not-cause-a-notification-for-experienced-users

Answer (score 0):

This request is not completed by any means. The notification bonanza at the top of the page continues at full speed.

Comment: Would have been good to have a screenshot attached.