# Is the top bar showing way too many messages?

Tags: discussion, user-interface, notification-bar

Whenever I visit any StackExchange site, I find myself constantly closing messages at the top bar. They keep coming at me one after another. They either welcome me, tell me to log in, tell me that I am already logged in or I earned this badge or that privilege. Finally the page moves up the way it is supposed to be.

I feel lucky if I only have to deal with two. Isn't this a little overkill? I suggest to put the rewards in the inbox. The auto login message is completely superfluous. OK, so you can keep track of me across sites. Congrats. So maybe a welcome message to the new comers and that's it.

I think pretty much everyone can tell that they are logged in when the welcome bar goes away. What do you think?

Comment: My solution to this problem: I never close those bars. They add a little color and I treat those few lost pixels at the top of the screen as normal. Granted that doesn't do anything for the auto-login message.

Comment: Your user record shows that you visit Stack Overflow only occasionally (about once every 8 days or so). It's not surprising that the messages accumulate between visits.

Comment: The "Welcome back OffBySome, you've been logged in. Click here to refresh the page." one is particularly annoying. Just refresh the page for me. And yes I've read the post about why it doesn't, but it is still very annoying.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Prevent the 'Notification Bar Fiesta'](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96951/prevent-the-notification-bar-fiesta)

Comment: @robert. Yes, I log in every now and then to a few sites. I just don't see the relevance of this notifications to my rare usage of SE sites. The messages can accumulate in the inbox where they are much less disruptive. The top part of the screen is actually very valuable property in screen real estate.