# The new notification system didn't notify me of my Investor badge :(

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, badges, notifications

Today I got awarded an Investor badge:

[image: enter code here]

... but the new notification system didn't show me no shiny grey (1) (or show me it at all...):

[image]

<sup>(it's not any further down, I promise)</sup>

Needless to say, I'm very angry:

[image]

Comment: You know what?  +1 just for that image at the end.

Comment: See animuson's answer, he's got it right.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's likely that the badge is **hidden for veterans** (i.e. users who have a 200-rep account somewhere on the network) in order to prevent clutter (which was implemented previously due to excessive notification bars). Other badges such as Autobiographer and Analytical are also hidden in this way.

See [Prevent the 'Notification Fiesta'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96951/prevent-the-notification-bar-fiesta)

I don't see any reason to change this behavior just because the notifications are crammed into a tiny box now instead of notification bars. Notifications are really meant to *notify* you that something has happened that you might not have expected. Offering your first bounty on a question: quite expected.

Comment: This is correct, by and large notification for the single award bronze badges are suppressed for "veteran" users.  Investor is one of those.

Comment: Gutted. I worked hard for 2 years and 3 months to get that badge.

Comment: Ah, so this is why I don't get the autobiographer badge notification every single site I sign up for

Comment: Perhaps we should move to reconsider this policy now that there's a saner way to notify people of things?

Comment: @TheEstablishment: Nah, there's still no point in showing them. I certainly wouldn't want my notifications box flooded with worthless bronze badges. And I do believe they are planning to use it for some other notifications as well, at least that's what Shog hinted at on chat.

Comment: @animuson: If badge is getting 1st time then notification should receive or not? Are there specific badges for which notifications doesn't come out ? Please help in http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138113/why-notifications-not-getting-for-all-badges-received