# Which badges do not cause a notification for experienced users?

Tags: support, badges, notifications, achievements-dialog

Yesterday, I have received two [badges](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1045444/somnath-muluk?tab=activity&sort=badges): Revival, and Self-Learner. However I was only notified of the Revival badge, because apparently the Self-Learner badge is not considered "[veteran-worthy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133556)".

What badges have their notification suppressed if the user has a 200-rep account somewhere on the Stack Exchange network, i.e. they won't trigger a new item in our achievements dialog?

Comment: IIRC, 200 rep is just the beginning. As you go on, even more badges are hidden.

Comment: @balpha - plan to make this into a faq or something like that?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd It's hardly "frequently asked" if it's the first time being asked. Also see [this discussion](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1012291#1012291).

Comment: @balpha cheers, I saw a table once posted by a mod/dev but your post is much more simple and informative.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Oh, okay, I haven't found one. Got a link?

Comment: @balpha sure! [Here it is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84225/orange-bar-not-appearing-when-a-new-privilege-is-earned/84317#84317). Hmm.. it's for privileges, but guess you have one for badges as well in the same place?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Silver and gold badges are always considered veteran-worthy, so you'll always be notified of those regardless of reputation or site.

On per-site metas, you're always considered a veteran; on all other sites (including Meta Stack Exchange), you're considered a veteran if you have the network association bonus rights, i.e. you have earned 200 rep somewhere in the past.

The following bronze badges are considered veteran-worthy:

- Nice Answer
- Nice Question
- Caucus
- Excavator
- Mortarboard
- Popular Question
- Proofreader
- Revival
- Synonymizer
- Vox Populi
- Announcer
- Precognitive
- Curious
- Tag badges

Any bronze badge not in this list is not veteran-worthy, i.e. won't cause a notification for veteran users.

Back before its [retirement](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/06/18/adios-to-unfriendly-badges-ahoy-lifejacket-and-lifeboat/), the Tumbleweed badge was also included on the above list.

Comment: Yes, if you have the SO `precognitive` badge, that IS noteworthy.

Comment: with 200 Rep a user is already considered a Veteran? What is a user with 20K Rep then? A hyper-mega-veteran?!? :-P

Comment: @donfuxx The idea is that after 200 rep, things like Autobiographer are not interesting; you easily get it on any site where you log in. But having a Nice Answer is nice even if you're JS and it's your 5770's Nice Answer.

Comment: Why is Excavator considered noteworthy? I don't know for others, but I have it on twenty sites.