# What defines a 'Veteran user'?

Tags: discussion, privileges

I've just found out the reason I don't get all my privelege and badge notifications because I am a 'Veteran user' on Stackoverflow.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84225/orange-bar-not-appearing-when-a-new-privilege-is-earned/

What defines a Veteran user?

- Should users be notified when they become a Veteran user?
- Or be given a Veteran badge?
- Should users be told what this mean?
- Or should this information be put in the FAQ?
- Is there a way to turn all notifications back on?

Comment: Please don't bring back the orange bar.

Comment: @casperOne - What was the orange bar?

Comment: Before you had the supercollider, notifications were delivered by an orange bar at the top of the screen which moved everything else on the page down.  They also had the tendency to stack when there were multiple ones, which were irritating, to say the least.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's some official documentation on the topic: [Which badges do not cause a notification for experienced users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138391/151015)

- According to the information shared by balpha there, if you are on a meta site or have more than 200 reputation, you are an experienced user.
- Getting 200 reputation is not something that is badge-worthy in my opinion, as it only takes about 4-5 good answers.
- No, it's not something that I think more than 1% would really care about (I personally don't).
- This information probably doesn't belong in the FAQ, as once again it doesn't really do much other than hide the 'Orange Bar'.
- No, as of right now you cannot turn back on the notifications.

Comment: Definitely; once I am aware of the fact of gaining privs at certain levels of rep, I no longer want to be bugged about it. I just hit 20k on SO, and any notification would have been pointless to me.