# Not receiving a badge notification

Tags: support, badges, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which badges do not cause a notification for experienced users?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138113/which-badges-do-not-cause-a-notification-for-experienced-users)

Today i was awarded with the Suffrage and Vox Populi badges. 40 minutes after reaching the 40 votes, i received the **You've earned the "Vox Populi" badge** in the Notification area (top left corner). But I haven't received the **Suffrage** notification. Why? is this a bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, some bronze badges are not shown in the notifications area, for users that are considered "experienced".

If you have more than one account on the Stack Exchange network (associated) then you won't be notified of the 'easy' bronze badges anymore. See [Prevent the 'Notification Fiesta'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96951/prevent-the-notification-fiesta).

You still get notified for Nice Question / Answer, even experienced users like those still. :-)