# How do we know which badge is earned?

Tags: discussion, badges, notifications

I recetly got one broze badge in stackoverflow making total of 12 but I dont know which one I earned. There should be a kind of notification for such kind of event.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You have several options:

- Look at your [activity tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2320808/deonia?tab=activity&sort=badges), awarded badges are named there.
- Look at your [badges tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2320808/deonia?tab=badges&sort=recent), sorted by recent. The top-left badge is the most recent.
- Look at your notifications, the exact badge you earned is named:

[image: notification area with badge notifications]

Note that once you associated your account with multiple Stack Exchange sites, you no longer receive notifications for certain 'low level' bronze badges to cut down on the noise a little. See [Prevent the 'Notification Fiesta'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96951/prevent-the-notification-fiesta)

Comment: @Chichiray I didnt get any notification . thats why I raised the concern

Comment: @Deonia after you reach 200+ rep you do not get a notification for bronze badges.

Comment: @TronicZomB In SO I have 744 rep but still I didt get notification :(

Comment: @Deonia: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/166249/not-receiving-a-badge-notification/166250#166250

Comment: @TronicZomB: No, it's when you have associated your account, and only certain bronze badges are no longer shown.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks got my answer

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah ok, I had thought I read 200+, I knew there was a "cutoff" of sorts for "experienced users", like you say in your other answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your profile and scroll down to the badges section. To the right of the word "Badges" is recent, class, and name. Click the recent option and then the top left badge is the most recent one you just earned.