# Not getting notifications on new badge being rewarded

Tags: discussion, support, notifications

I was recently awarded a new badge but didn't receive notification for that in inbox. I observed that in the two recent badges that I was awarded.

Is this the default behavior on Meta or something is not working?

Comment: [Which badges do not cause a notification for experienced users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138113/which-badges-do-not-cause-a-notification-for-experienced-users/)

Comment: I guess it was the `Informed` and `Critic` badges in [meta]. If so, as you already got them in [SO] you don't get a notification again.

Answer (score -1):

The following bronze badges notified to users:

```
Nice Answer
Nice Question
Caucus
Excavator
Mortarboard
Popular Question
Proofreader
Revival
Synonymizer
Tumbleweed
Vox Populi
Announcer
Precognitive
any tag-based bronze badge
```

other bronze badges are not notified to users.

Comment: I have always been notified about many of these.

Comment: hmmm... updated now it was opposite.

Comment: It's more complicated than either revisions of this answer make it out to be. You are notified of certain bronze badges, until your reputation passes a certain threshold. Then you're considered to be a "veteran" user, probably not going to get super excited about some badges for basic usage of the site, and would rather not have these cluttering up your inbox. All documented [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138113/which-badges-do-not-cause-a-notification-for-experienced-users/).

Comment: Insead of copying another answer it would have been better to vote/flag as duplicate.