# Why do I keep getting a notification for earning the Autobiographer badge with no reputation changes?

Tags: support, bug, design, badges, achievements-dialog

The You've earned the "Autobiographer" badge (Complete "About Me" section of user profile) achievement keeps popping for me everytime i visit Stack Overflow[image]

Is it a bug?
It's irritating seeing the achievement icon turn green (indicating earning a new achievement) only to see this stale thing over and over again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a bug.

This badge is awarded **per site**, so when you join 10 sites, you will get 10 badges since the About Me is being copied upon account association. As you can see to the left of the badge icon, that one was for Movies.SE site you joined today.

**However**, once you get 200 reputation on one site, you are considered a "[veteran user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138113/which-badges-do-not-cause-a-notification-for-experienced-users/138391#138391)", and you'll stop being notified about "trivial" badges like this one. (You will still get them, just without notification in your inbox.)

Comment: it shouldn't keep popping for every site though right? it's just copying the data over,why do i need a notification? seems unnecessary

Comment: @KaranHarshWardhan only few (in percentage) people join more than one or two sites. So the SE team never really give it much thought. They also assume that one will join many sites only when having 200+ rep on one site, then indeed, no such notifications will appear. :)

Comment: nice insight into the usage patterns. thanks. i've always wondered why the signup process is so involved for sister stack sites when all it should be is "join this community also"