# Is the alert for new badges not shown anymore?

Tags: discussion, badges, alerts

I thought that, when I first started using Stack Exchange sites, I received alerts for every new badges I earned. I no longer see this happening, and it hasn't happened for awhile.

Have the alerts for new badges been discontinued?

Comment: After you gain a certain level of experience, certain badge notifications stop as some people get the bronze badges all the time.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133553/the-new-notification-system-didnt-notify-me-of-my-investor-badge or http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96951/prevent-the-notification-fiesta also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you gain 200 rep, most bronze level badges will no longer send notifications. Silver and gold badges will always send notifications though.