# Notification missing?

Tags: support, badges, notifications

Sometimes I get a badge and do not get an inbox notification from it. How does this work? Is it a bug?
I've tried to find for settings, but I didn't change anything and sometimes it shows me one and sometimes not so it shouldn't be a setting I think...

Comment: As a veteran user you are not notified for certain bronze badge AFAIK.

Comment: By design, following [this feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96951/prevent-the-notification-fiesta/96955#96955).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this isn't a bug. You won't get notifications for some bronze badges. I think this is because some users get them quite often

Comment: @Monica good point, edited my answer a bit

Comment: Thanks for the answer, makes sense now.